# How can I get warnings in my Objective-C code on an empty line?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

as I couldn't get rid of some warnings, although my code seemed to be ok, I copied Joe Conways (Conway/Hillegass: Objective-C Programming, 3rd edition) code into my project and got some funny warnings at empty lines. The code works fine (as it did before copying).
Any suggestions?

[image: xcode error]

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing special, probably XCode didn't update the line numbers of the warnings. Re-build it and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you! Oh well, I rebuilt it a dozen times before and the warnings still remained. Yes, now it's ok.

Comment: Sometimes you can clear up that problem by closing just that file with control-command-W.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "Project->Clean" and then rebuild. Should get rid of them.